# Displaying current datetime in MessageBox in C#

Tags: c#, string, datetime, messagebox

I know this is very trivial but I can't seem to find the answer as I have never done C#. Searched on Google but in vain.

I am trying to display current datetime in MessageBox in C# but I get following error

`Cannot convert datetime into string`.

Here is the code:

```
DateTime current = DateTime.Now;
MessageBox.Show(current.ToString);
```

Comment: Maybe he has answered 32% of his own questions...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ToString is a method. You need to do this:

```
MessageBox.Show(current.ToString());
```

Answer (score 3):

You are getting **compile time** error, because `ToString` is a **method** `.ToString()` not a **property**.

Answer (score 2):

you forget to add open and close parenthesis in the `ToString` Method

```
DateTime current = DateTime.Now;
MessageBox.Show(current.ToString());
```

Answer (score 1):

change `current.ToString` to `current.ToString()` ToString is a function not a property

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the following:

```
MessageBox.Show(DateTime.Now.ToString());
```